# Alias remote network after ssh

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-access

If I ssh into a remote machine (remote1, say), is it possible to alias the network that machine is on so that I could easily refer to a different remote machine, ie ssh remote2.remote_network rather than having to ssh onto remote1 and then ssh onto remote2 from there (Just so you know, I can only ssh into the remote network through remote1).

I think dynamic forwarding might be a solution, but I can't work out if I'm doing it wrong or just barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you want the `ProxyCommand` config option.  There's a perfect example of how to use it in your situation in the `ssh_config`(5) man page.

Comment: Coupled with Host *.remotes in my .ssh/config this works brilliantly. Thanks!